# Why using PosixFilePermission to set permissions on directory does not work

Tags: java, java.nio.file

Below is my code:

```
String DirectoryPath = "/Users/xxx/uploads/image";
Path newDirectoryPath = Paths.get(DirecotryPath);

if (!Files.exists(newDirectoryPath)) {
    Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx");
    FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> fileAttributes = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(permissions);
    Files.createDirectories(newDirectoryPath, fileAttributes);
}
```

After creating the directory, the permission of the directory is not 777.

Answer (score 10):

It's because of the actual [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) setting of the executing user.

From [PosixFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/PosixFileAttributeView.html)

> **When the access permissions are set at file creation time then the actual value of the permissions may differ that the value of the attribute object**. The reasons for this are implementation specific. On UNIX systems, for example, a process has a umask that impacts the permission bits of newly created files. Where an implementation supports the setting of the access permissions, and the underlying file system supports access permissions, then it is required that the value of the actual access permissions will be equal or less than the value of the attribute provided to the createFile or createDirectory methods. **In other words, the file may be more secure than requested.**

example

**Posix.java**

```
// add the omitted import statements
public class Posix {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Path newDirectoryPath = Paths.get("/tmp/image");
        Files.deleteIfExists(newDirectoryPath);
        Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions
                = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwxrwx");
        FileAttribute<Set<PosixFilePermission>> fileAttributes
                = PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(permissions);
        Files.createDirectories(newDirectoryPath, fileAttributes);
    }
}
```

execute in the shell

```
$ cd /tmp
$ javac Posix.java

$ umask 001
$ java Posix
$ ls -ld image/

drwxrwxrw-. 2 suboptimal suboptimal 6 Jul  5 12:38 image/

$ umask 002
$ java Posix
$ ls -ld image/

drwxrwxr-x. 2 suboptimal suboptimal 6 Jul  5 12:38 image/

$ umask 004
$ java Posix
$ ls -ld image/

drwxrwx-wx. 2 suboptimal suboptimal 6 Jul  5 12:38 image/
```